# Can I run container from an image twice

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

I used `docker run` command, in interactive mode, to downloaded a docker image for busybox and create a container for the same.

After exiting from the container, I tried `run` command again, without interactive mode, to create another container of busybox from the image already present in the local repo. While checking the list of active containers through `ps`, I do not see any new container running, but in the list of all containers `ps -a` I see new container created and Exited(0).

Though I can `start` an inactive container through its id, I am wondering why `run` command is exiting the container after creating it.

[image: docker cli]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of using `busybox` non-interactively. That's because the `busybox` image just runs `sh`.

To see that, take a look at the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/busybox/blob/8d817055ba8420f907825ca650370a727c4cb1f2/uclibc/Dockerfile):

```
FROM scratch
ADD busybox.tar.xz /
CMD ["sh"]
```

A Docker container will stop as soon as the process that runs in the container terminates. So when you start `busybox` non-interactively, the shell will exit, and so the container will terminate.

If you have a Docker image with a process capable of running non-interactively, you can use `-d` to keep the container alive in non-interactive mode. (If that fails, I suggest taking a look at `docker logs [containername]` to see what's happening under the hood.)

For example, this will run indefinitely non-interactively: `docker run -d --rm busybox sh -c "while :; do sleep 500; done"`